# The difference in connecting the FB LM2596 before or after the output capacitor

Tags: dc-dc-converter, feedback

There is a step-down converter (12V / 5V) based on the LM2596. It has a voltage regulation function based on a tuning resistor.

There should be feedback at the controller output (FB line)

[image]

In my example, the feedback line is connected to the output of the inductor.

After the inductor, an output capacitor is connected.

**Question:**

Is there a difference in connecting FeedBack before or after the output capacitor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, no. Your traces are short enough. But there are situations where it matters, such as remote sense application. Or when too much capacitive load causes the regulator to swing.

Oh and btw, definitely put some MLCC in parallel to that big electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: Roker Pivic, thank you for the answer!

Would a good choice be to use a mlcc capacitor with a capacity of 10uF?
Murata, 805, 10uF, 16V, X7R

Should it be placed after a large electrolytic capacitor or before it?

Is it also worth adding the same capacitor at the input?

Comment: The best course of action would be to follow the recommendations from your chip producer. However, typical rule of thumb is 2 orders of magnitude difference in capacitance to the bigger cap. X7R should be fine, but check for capacitance variations with the voltage in the datasheet. X7Rs are known for their piezoelectric effect. Placement is not crucial in this case.